# command line create maven web project failure

Tags: maven

with maven 3.0.3 in windows 7 cmd console:

*mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId="com.maven" -DartifactId="web" -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false*

maven-archetype-quickstart works but maven-achetype-webapp doesn't:

*mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId="com.maven" -DartifactId="web" -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-achetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false*

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.212s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Feb 12 17:02:01 EST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/154M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does
not exist (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-achetype-webapp:1.0) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Did you try doing this with maven 3.0.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might have a typo: shouldn't it be `maven-aRchetype-webapp` instead? (the R is missing)